# Weird Input in Code::Blocks console

Tags: c, console

[image: I was typing 123]

When I typed numbers, CodeBlocks console displayed weird characters, but the letters work fine.
I have tried with other codes and the Numlock button but there were no different. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please include your code, not only the screenshot!

Comment: i did test with different codes and the keyboard Nunlock but there was no different.

Comment: What character encoding is set?

Comment: I'm not sure. I think its Unicode

Comment: The number keys on the numeric pad and the letters worked when I tried. I think only the normal number keys that don't work

Comment: Other applications (such as Notepad) work with the numeric keys correctly?

Comment: yes, only the codeblocks console that doesn't work